# jQuery - is it bad to have multiple $(document).ready(function() {});

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it bad to have multiple `$(document).ready(function() {});` on your page? I have a website where I load different things at different times. I fire off those partial postback functions inside `$(document).ready()` but i have about 4 or 5 on the page at once. Is this a bad practice? Specifically, will it cause any performance issues?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**This answer is no longer relevant. Please see other posts below for more up-to-date jQuery $.ready() impacts. This post is over 3 years old.**

See: http://jsperf.com/docready/11

> The answer is no! You can litter them as much as you want (note the
>   word litter). They just become a queue of events that are called when
>   the ready event is triggered.
>
> http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready

Answer (score 11):

The answer is actually "Yes it deters performance":

http://jsperf.com/docready/3

Comment: You're drawing conclusions based on your opinion.  The answer is that there is a performance hit (everything has a performance hit) and that hit should be weighed against the benefits of it.  Even with IE8 it would take 20K $.ready calls to slow down my page by 1 second.  The 50 - 100 that I do use would result in an increase of about 0.0025 seconds on IE or 0.000125 seconds on Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

No it is fine to have as many as you want. A shorter, much more elegant way to do this is `$(function(){})` though.

Answer (score 1):

If it's on the same page I would personally put them all in the same place so that you can't be caught out by forgetting one of the things happening on load.

I doubt the performance implications are that significant though. Have you tried benchmarking the page with them all together and apart?

Answer (score -1):

If any of them throw an exception, it blocks the rest from running. This can be very difficult to debug with code "littered" across multiple source files (esp. 3rd party libraries).