# Can I attach more than one functions to Document.Load using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am planning on separating independent `.js` files and I wonder if I can use them together after that.

The problem might be that **all** of them have something similar to

```
$(function() { code here };
```

Is it safe to make jQuery to run multiple times, from different locations, this method?

Comment: Yes. It's not a problem at all.

Comment: Possibly related: *[What happens when you have two jQuery $(document).ready calls in two JavaScript files used on the same HTML page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435868/what-happens-when-you-have-two-jquery-document-ready-calls-in-two-javascript-f/6435978#6435978)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that should be fine. And you can reuse document.ready() too (info from jQuery docs [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMultiple_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using many .js files you might want to use require.js (http://requirejs.org/).  This framework will optimize the loading of multiple scripts.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**

I see no reason why wouldn't you be able to "run" jQuery multiple times.. It's function and function is about to be albe to be called multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  `.ready(callback)` is shorthand for `.bind("ready", callback);`.  Event bind calls in jQuery let you add multiple handlers for a single event.