# How to check JavaScript execution history on DOM

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="box"></div>

// First script
$('.box').width(100);

// Second script
$('.box').addClass('color');

// Third script
$('.box').fadeOut();
```

#### result:

```
<div class="color" style="width: 100px; display: none;"></div>
```

It might has change to do something to one DOM by different js file, if the script code was separated to many js file, it's really hard to find out the div was affected by who, is there any tool could check the execution history on DOM?

Comment: Wouldn't simple logging solve the problem?

Comment: You can set breakpoints on tree modification, for example.

Comment: You may want to check this [link][1] out first.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435868/what-happens-when-you-have-two-jquery-document-ready-calls-in-two-javascript

Comment: @dfsq Isn't breakpoints is use on JavaScript code, but in my case I don't know the div was changed by who

Comment: I mean you can set breakpoints in Chrome developer tools on subtree modifications, attributes modifications ...

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is, you just need to open developer tools (F12), open network section activate it (if not activated, happens alot in IE) and refresh your site, you will see all the tracing that has occurred on your web and every file that was called in the order it was called.

Comment: It's not like answer my question

Comment: a tool to check the execution history is only the network section in developer tools, as js is created on the run. The only way to debug js through a compiler is using IE when you run it and only in VS.