# Jquery - sometimes working script

Tags: jquery, html, document

Consider the following script for checking if search form is empty. The id's of search buttons are: `mainSearch` and `searchIcon`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mainSearch').click(function() {
                if($("input[type=text][name=search]").val() == "" || $("input[type=text][name=search]").val() == 'Напишете търсената дума'
                || $("input[type=text][name=search]").val() == 'Enter search keywords here')
                    return false;
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#searchIcon').click(function() {
                if($("input[type=text][name=q]").val() == "" ) 
                    return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

HTMLscheme:

```
<div class="searchForm">
            <form action="search.php" method="get">
                <input type="text" name="search" id="searchForm" value="<?php if(checkBgLanguage()) echo 'Напишете търсената дума'; else echo 'Enter search keywords here'; ?>" autocomplete="off"
                maxlength="35"/>
                <a href="search.php"><img src="css/imgs/searchIcon.png" width="24" height="24" id="mainSearch"/></a>
            </form></div>
```

For some reason the second function is working on every page. The first function works only on the home page. Another problem is pressing enter button; nobody should submit clear form with enter. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the relevant html sections as well?

Comment: I don't get it. How are you using these? Returning false from an event handler is probably not going to do what you want. Also, you don't need two document.ready functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put both those functions into a single `$(document).ready(){}` block, as each block will slow down your page by binding the event respectively. You can also use the shorthand `$(function(){});`. From there, try `event.preventDefault()` instead of returning false:

```
$(function(){
    $('#mainSearch').click(function(event) {
        var val = $("input[type=text][name=search]").val();
        if(val == "" || val == 'Напишете търсената дума'
            ||val == 'Enter search keywords here') {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $('#searchIcon').click(function(event) {
        var val = $("input[type=text][name=q]").val();
        if(val == "" ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need one `$(document).ready(function() {`

Try changing to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var texts = [ 'Enter search keywords here' 
                 ,'Напишете търсената дума'];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').bind('submit', function(e) {
           var errors = 0;
           if('' === $("input[type=text][name=q]").val()) {
               errors++;
           }
           $(texts).each(function(i,x) {
               if(x === $("input[type=text][name=q]").val()) {
                   errors++;
               };
           )};

           if(0 != errors) {
               e.preventDefault();
               return false;
           }

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I thought that might be an issue, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148241/jquery-is-it-bad-to-have-multiple-document-readyfunction...

Comment: @BertEvans http://jsperf.com/docready/3 Multiple doc ready events slow down the page.

Comment: @PHPBree Cool beans! Nice to know.