# jQuery: is having multiple $(function) in same script file is wrong?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - is it bad to have multiple $(document).ready(function() {});](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148241/jquery-is-it-bad-to-have-multiple-document-readyfunction)
>   [Can you have multiple $(document).ready(function() sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections)

Here is my one and only jQuery file for the project

```
// loading search page
$(function(){
  $("#search").click(function() {
    $("#feature").load("templates/search.html", function() {
        $("#search-input").focus();
        $("#search-input").css({
            "margin-left": "20%",
            "margin-top" : "2%"
        });
    });
 });
});

/* 
finding youtube videos
API source : https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc
*/
$(function(){
    $('#search-input').live('keyup',function() {
        var search_input = $(this).val();
        var keyword = encodeURIComponent(search_input);
        var yt_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+keyword+'&format=5&max-results=10&v=2&alt=jsonc';

        $.ajax({
          url: yt_url,
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            //called when complete
          },
          success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
            if(response.data.items) {
                var template = $('#item').clone();
                $('#result').html(template);
                $.each(response.data.items, function(i, data) {
                    //console.log(data)
                    search_data = {
                        'id': data.id,
                        'title': data.title,
                        'views': data.viewCount,
                        'thumbnail': data.thumbnail['sqDefault'],
                    }
                    item = video_result_template(search_data);
                    $('#result').append(item).fadeIn('slow');
                });
            } else {

            }
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //called when there is an error
          }
        });
    });
});

// filling out the search template
function video_result_template(data) {
    var item = $('#item').clone();
    item.removeClass('hide-item');
    item.find('img').attr('src', data.thumbnail);
    item.find('.title').html(data.title);
    item.find('.views').html(data.views);
    item.attr('id', data.id);
    item.addClass('view-item');
    return item;
}

// playing the video from search result on player pane
$(function(){
    $('.item').live('click', function(){
        // alert(this.id);
        var url = $('#video-frame').attr('src');
        var new_url = url.replace(/embed\/[\w -]*/g, 'embed/' + this.id);
        $('#video-frame').attr('src', new_url);
    });
});

// creating new playlist
$(function() {
    $('form input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function() {
        var val = $.trim(this.value);
        $('form .create-playlist-button').prop('disabled', val.length == 0).click(function(e){
            var title = $(e.target).closest('.video-detail').find('.title').text();
            alert(title);
        });
    });

    // $('form .create-playlist-button').live('click', function(e){
    //  var title = $(e.target).closest('.video-detail').find('.title').text();
    //  alert('title');
    // });
        // $('form .create-playlist-button').prop('disabled', val.length == 0).click(function(){
        //          alert($('.title').get(1).textContent);
        //      });

});

// animating slideshow on landing page
$(function(){
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        pagination: true,
        preloadImage: '../static/img/loading.gif',
        play: 2000,
        pause: 1000,
        hoverPause: true
    });

    $('.slides_control').css({
        "height": "600px",
        "margin-right": "400px"
    });

    $('.pagination').hide('');
});
```

**Question**

- This jquery page has multiple $(function)(means when DOM is ready) functions, is that incorrect?  Given that
- some jQuery functions apply to different pages
- some element appear later on the page (see load() function)

How does all that work? I am not very sure, but it seems like there is something wrong here which means there is absolutely a chance to learn from people who do it regularily

P.S - I am absolutely new to the land of jQuery. I have been trying to work on my first project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES** you can use it in this way without any error, but to make your code more `neat` and `readable` you should not repeat the tags un-necessarily.

***Note:*** Variable declared in one function will not be accessible in other functions so you will need to be careful about variable scope in repeating function bodies.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$(function() {..});` you actually do: `$(document).ready(function() {..});` which is register a function to the ready event of the document.
What you did is like register several functions to a single click event which is valid and correct.

Hope I am clear.