# document-ready v/s body-ready v/s window-ready event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

What's the different between these three events?

Which one loads before/after others?

```
   <body> 
        <script type='text/javascript'> 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log('Document %s',+new Date());
            });
            $('body').ready(function(){
                console.log('Body %s',+new Date());
            });
            $(window).ready(function(){
                console.log('Window %s',+new Date());
            }); 
        </script>
        <div>hello world</div>
    </body>
```

Strange thing is that , they fires on the same order as I put them on code. For current example. `document` one fires first and `windows` one fires at the last.

p.s. I've read [window.onload vs <body onload=""/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload) ,
[window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload) and few others.

Comment: Those all do exactly the same thing, and your observation about the functions running in declaration order is correct.

Comment: Anything special in `document` version, as everyone uses it.

Comment: Actually I prefer simply `$(function() { ... });` which is also exactly the same. It's shorter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are exactly the same, and actually the argument passed to `$(...)` doesn't matter.

---

From the **[jQuery documentation about `.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**:

> ### .ready( handler )
>
> **handler** - A function to execute after the DOM is ready.

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> - `$(document).ready(handler)`
> - `$().ready(handler)` (this is not recommended)
> - `$(handler)`

> The `.ready()` method can only be called on a jQuery object matching
>   the current document, so the selector can be omitted.

As seen the argument (*selector*) to `$()` is explicitly said to be optional (when doing `$(...).ready`), because of this we can safely assume that it's irrelevant to the end result.

Comment: Also from the documentation: "The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted."

Comment: oh. I always thought `$(function() { ... });` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){....});` only. Thanks for verifying. I have read jQuery docs earlier but you explained it in the way I can understand

Comment: @Jashwant this might be helpful for the other part of your question ,the executing order http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148241/jquery-is-it-bad-to-have-multiple-document-readyfunction